# Dagger with Java AWS Lambda?

Tags: dependency-injection, aws-lambda, dagger

I'm struggling to come up with a solution where I can use Dagger and Lambda. The main issue seems that dependency injection happens in the constructor, while you have to provide at least one 0-arg-constructor in Lambda. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've come up to (and [blogged about](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2021/10/19/dagger-java-lambda/)) is to make your zero-args constructor retrieve the constructed Dagger configuration i.e.:

```java
public Handler() {
  this(DaggerConfig.create().serviceLayer());
}

/* test only */ Handler(ServiceLayer service) {
  this.service = service;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to provide 0-arg-constructor. Try lambda event and extend request handler.
guice, spring resolve the dependency on runtime, which might increase your cold start time. On the other hand, dagger2 resolves dependency on compile time.
For more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plK0zyRLIP8

https://github.com/shivaramani/aws-dagger-lambda